# AngularJs routeProvider error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am facing problem with routeProvider, don't know why its not working. The problem is with the config function .Here's the code

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.config(['$routeProvider' ,function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'indexController'
    }).
    when('/first', {
        templateUrl: 'first.html',
        controller: 'firstCtrl'
    }).
    when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'second.html',
        controller: 'secondCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'index.html'
    });
}])

mainApp.controller('indexController', [function() {
    this.outputString = "String from the index controller";
}]);

mainApp.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.outputString = "String from the first controller";
}]);

mainApp.controller('secondCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.outputString = "String from first controller";
}]);
```

[image: Error Info]

Comment: can you add your index page. that will be more  helpful

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: @SumeetDewangan Did my answer work for you? Let me know if you still have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is missing the angular-route module.

Make sure you add it with:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

or, if you are using bower, add `"angular-route": "^1.4.0"` to `bower.json` and run `bower install`.

Last, make sure you are injecting `ngRoute` into you application

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/5/).